# How to install the Steam version of DC Universe Online using the DCUO install CD's?

Tags: steam, dc-universe-online

I recently had to reinstall everything on my computer due to system and hardware failure.

What I would like to do is to install the DC Universe Online game on Steam. However, when I use the DVD's that are included with it, I cannot use or access the in-game overlay. I've done this with other games (such as Mass Effect 1, 2, and 3) where I can use the non-Steam version and play it through Steam to get the overlay.

I know it's purely cosmetic and the what not but I still want to do it.

So again, my question is:

Is there a way to use the DC Universe Online installation CD's to install the game through Steam? Or are they two different version and no way to patch one to be the other?

Comment: Have you tried using the "Add a game.." -> "Add a non-steam game" method?  This lets you use the Steam overlay with practically any game.  (for instance, I use it with Diablo 3, which is unavailable through Steam via any means)

Comment: Yup I've tried that method originally when Steam first put it on their market. The game would run but it wouldn't allow me to use the overlay.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question... you own both the steam and a non-steam version, and want to install the game from the non-steam disks while having the steam overlay available when playing?

Comment: @ronno It is free to play, and anyway steam opens the launcher just as the retail version does.

Comment: @ronno Yes. I bought the game when it was still Pay to Play. I wanted to use the retail discs to get the Steam Overlay but it appears it only appears when the game is installed via Steam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following:

- Start the download, stop it immediately, and close steam completely.
- Copy over the files installed from the CDs to steam\steamapps\common\[folder steam installs it to]
- Now run steam and validate files for the game. Steam should recognize most of the files.

From http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=22664018&postcount=5

Comment: I do this with alot of games, when transfering from PC to PC. I also did it with bf2 Disc to Steam. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

DC Universe Online is free to play on Steam. You can just download it from there.

Comment: Trying to avoid re-downloading 16GB's

Comment: @paulwilliams Sorry, the steam version uses slightly different binaries.

Comment: It actually only uses one or two slightly different binaries and those are the ones tied into Steam. Otherwise its copying the same game. It's essentially how I managed to get the Steam version of the game to let me patch onto the PBE/Test server. The game will do the minor patching. As I said, it beats re-downloaded 20GB and turns what would be a 20GB download into a 253MB download instead.